Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot assign value of type '(any AuthInterop)?' to type 'any AuthInterop'
Problem Keywords: Firebase, Flutter, and iOS.
While I encounter no issues with the Android part, I have been unable to successfully build for iOS. Below are the error codes I am experiencing.
Flutter version: 3.22.3 Stable
XCode: 15.4 (latest version at the time of release)
"flutter doctor" results: All checks are green.
The issue arises when running the flutter build ios command.
When using version 10.22.0 of the firebase-ios-sdk package:
Uncategorized (Xcode): Could not resolve package dependencies:
  file not found at path:
  /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dzholwmcosvbzjckrwbsnmmxsodb/SourcePackages/artifacts/firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics-rc1.
  zip
  fatalError


When using version 11.0.0 of the firebase-ios-sdk package:
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Value of optional type '(any StorageProvider)?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'storage' of wrapped base type 'any StorageProvider'
/Users/username/Desktop/project/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Storage.swift:72:11


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Value of optional type '(any StorageProvider)?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'storage' of wrapped base type 'any StorageProvider'
/Users/username/Desktop/project/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Storage.swift:87:11


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot assign value of type '(any AuthInterop)?' to type 'any AuthInterop'
/Users/username/Desktop/project/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Storage.swift:290:38


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot assign value of type '(any AppCheckInterop)?' to type 'any AppCheckInterop'
/Users/username/Desktop/project/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Storage.swift:292:46


Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide!
Steps I Have Taken to Resolve the Issue:

Uninstalling and reinstalling XCode.
Trying different versions of XCode.
Testing different versions of the Firebase iOS SDK package.
Using CocoaPods instead of XCode for package installation.


Its ok. The reason for this error is that I included firebase packages with any package manager for ios while integrating firebase into the project in the flutter application. When it comes to flutter, a package should not be included. Applying firebase documentation is wrong, FlutterFire documentation should be applied completely and without any excess. As some people say, do not try to learn swift and interfere with these codes, these are not your codes, they are located in the root directory of firebase packages.

I am facing same error after updating cocoa pods. What was your solution for this?

@shababhsiddique
it think you should remove all firebase packages/dependencies from cocoa pods

That was four totally useless and time wasting attempts to fix the problem.
Step 1: Learn Swift.
Step 2: Tell us what T? means.
Step 3: Tell us how if let… and guard let… work.
Step 4: With this knowledge, read the error message and easily fix your problem.
